# Azure build pipeline NuGet Restore error NETSDK1045

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created an Azure CI pipeline through Visual Studio 2019. The project target framework is .net core 3.1. However, during the NuGet Restore it fails.
I have .Net Core 2.2.2017 and 3.1.101 installed on my computer and my Visual Studio 2019 community version is 16.4. My environment variables paths are in place.

I also tried creating an app service manually that uses .net core 3.1 LTS stack but I still get the same error.

```
    ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.110\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):

    error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.
```

This is the YAML file generated by Visual Studio

```
pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.0.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.0.0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishSymbols@1
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, you do not need to install NuGetToolInstaller and vsbuild, you should firstly install DotNetCoreCLI after that you can use it[. Here is manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) how your yaml file should looks like.

Comment: I don't get it why the template provided by the Visual Studio didn't work for the build pipeline. But publishing from the IDE is no pain, but the con is it is not automated.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing by the IDE has no pain because it use the tools you have installed on your machine, in the pipeline you need to specify the toolin you gonna use and that is the pain.

For those who are not using the new YAML based pipeline but instead use classic editor on devops you might need to add dot net core add task and change from nuget restore to dotnet restore task

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I create a pipeline from the Azure Devops UI, my YAML looks like the below.  It uses `DotNetCoreCLI` instead of `VSBuild`.  Notice that it uses the `Restore` command instead of anything having to do with Nuget.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```